# Why am I getting this error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"?

Tags: python, flask

I'm attempting to create a simple flask app that rolls dice. The error appears to be happening at the line:

```
for roll_num in range(quantity):
```

How do I solve this error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from random import randint

app = Flask(__name__)

class Die():
    """A class representing a single die."""

        def __init__(self, num_sides):
    """Initialize a single die."""
        self.num_sides = num_sides

    def roll(self):
        """Return a random value between 1 and number of sides"""
        return randint(1, self.num_sides)

global dice_roll
dice_roll = Die

@app.route('/entry')
def entry_page():
    return render_template('entry.html', the_title='Welcome to Roll the Bones!')

@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def roll_die():
    global dice_roll

    sides = request.form['sides']
    quantity = request.form['quantity']
    title = 'Here are your results:'

    die = Die(sides)

    results = []
    for roll_num in range(quantity):
        result = die.roll()
        results.append(result)

    return render_template('results.html', the_title=title, the_sides=sides, the_quantity=quantity, the_results=results)
```

Comment: @Kurohige yeah i did try that but it doesn't work

Comment: maybe usign `sides = int(request.form['sides'])` could help

Comment: @Kurohige yes that worked!

Comment: sorry wrong line

Comment: Please add the stack trace of your error!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the values sent from the browser are not being represented as their correct Type after they are POSTed.

```
sides = request.form['sides']
quantity = request.form['quantity']
```

One or both of these need to be wrapped in an `int()`

```
sides = int(request.form['sides'])
quantity = int(request.form['quantity'])
```

I believe `quantity` is being represented as a String.